# Not getting data while querying view using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to query a view using NHibernate, but receving an empty result always.

**View name:** vw_lead_review_detail

Code snippet for View mapping:

```
[Class(NameType = typeof(LeadReviewDetail), Table = "vw_lead_review_detail", Lazy = false, Schema = "affiliate")]
public class LeadReviewDetail
{
    [Id(Name = "LeadEventId", Column = "lead_event_id", UnsavedValue = "0")]
    [Generator(1, Class = "assigned")]
    public virtual int? LeadEventId { get; set; }
    [Property(Column = "addition_input_value")]
    public virtual string AdditionInputValue { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anything else do I need to change in this mapping class?
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to debug this:

- Have your mapping been actually loaded? (NHibernate returns empty result if you query for a class that has no mapping.)
- Enable NHibernate detailed logging and examine the SQL produced.